# Factorise $3\cos(x) - 2\sin(x) + 1$

Tags: trigonometry

How can I find the "product form" of
$3\cos(x) - 2\sin(x) + 1$
I cannot find a way to get rid of the coefficients (3 and 2)

Comment: Perhaps substitution $x=2t$ will help.

Comment: What do you mean by "product form"? You can write it as $1+\sqrt{13}\cos(x+\tan^{-1}\frac23)$.

Comment: $3\cos x-2\sin x+1=\cos x (3-2\tan x+\sec x)$

Comment: @LukeCollins I'd like to study the minimum and the maximum of this function so what i want is only one trigonometric function, how can I get this form ? ($1 + \sqrt{13}\cos(x+\tan^{-1}\frac{2}{3})$ ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To express $a\cos x + b\sin x$ in the form $R\cos(x-\alpha)$, just notice that by the compound angle identity,

\begin{align*}
a\cos x+ b\sin x &\equiv R\cos(x-\alpha)\\
&= \underbrace{R\cos\alpha}_{a}\cos x+\underbrace{R\sin\alpha}_b \sin x,
\end{align*}
so we can just solve the system $a=R\cos\alpha$ and $b=R\sin\alpha$ simultaneously to get that $$R = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} $$
and $$\alpha=\tan^{-1}\tfrac ba.$$

In your case, we get $$3\cos x - 2\sin x \equiv \sqrt{13}\cos(x+\tan^{-1}\tfrac23),$$
which means that $$-\sqrt{13}\leqslant 3\cos x-2\sin x\leqslant \sqrt{13}.$$
Adding $1$ throughout, we get the bounds
$$1-\sqrt{13}\leqslant 3\cos x-2\sin x+1\leqslant 1+\sqrt{13},$$
so the minimum is $1-\sqrt{13}$.